# Sending mails to recipients always from predefined sender-address

Tags: plugins, thunderbird, mailing

Since I've different sender addresses in my Thunderbird mailingclient, and I'm always sending mails to 
some clients with the wrong sender address (I know, looking twice would be great) I wanted to ask if anybody knows a plugin or something else where I can something like map a mailing address to a sender address so that every time when a mail is sent to this specific mailing address the specified sender address is used e.g. a mail to kirk.hammett@metallica.com should always be sent from thrash@metal.com but a mail to james.t.kirk@enterprise.com should always be sent from spaceacademy@starfleet.sf or so.

Comment: i've looked around a lot but there is nothing which could accomplish such a task. i wonder if anybody else had such a request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fainally i found two plugins which serve the above purpose

- Identity chooser
- correct identity